# How To Refresh a View Using NSNotification without [view setNeedsDisplay];

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two classes, one ***UIViewController*** and one ***UITableViewCell***, called ***MoodViewController*** and ***TableViewCell*** respectively.

The ***MoodViewController*** has an image view, which I would like to refresh every time a ***UISwitch*** state changes. I am posting a notification on the switch state change, and the notification is being received. However, I can't figure out what code to use within the Notification handler that will allow me to refresh the image view automatically. I have tried ***[myImageViewName setNeedsDisplay];*** however, I cannot seem to get a view to refresh after the Notification is received.

The code that I am currently using to handle the notification is as follows:

```
-(void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {

NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"switchKey"] isEqual: @"On"]) {

    self.aReference.moodLabel.text = @"Happy";
    self.aReference.moodImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: _array1[0]];
    [self.aReference.moodImage setNeedsDisplay];
}
else {

    self.aReference.moodImage.image = nil;
    [self.aReference.moodImage setNeedsDisplay];

}
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Note: I am trying to refresh the image view which is NOT part of the table, so please don't suggest [tableViewName reloadData]; unless I am missing something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated -- Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work.

One possible explanation for it not working is that `self.aReference.moodImage` (or `self.aReference`) is `nil` when the notification handler is executed. Please, check this.

Comment: Thanks, Sergio. 'self.aReference' isn't 'nil' when the notification handler is executed. Any other thoughts to troubleshoot?

Comment: Is `[UIImage imageNamed: _array1[0]]` not nil?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the notification is being sent to another thread? You could make sure that the UI changes are done in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're removing the observer on first call to the handler?

Try removing the line -

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

This line will remove self from all notifications that self is observing.